# Controller inheritance problem from a plugin controller in cakephp 4

Tags: inheritance, controller, cakephp-4.x

I'm building a `NewsManager` plugin that has a `NewsController` in the `Admin` prefix.

I want this controller could both be used as it is (with the route `/admin/news-manager/news/*`) or as a parent controller that could be overload by inherance.

Here is my code :

```php
// plugins/NewsManager/Controller/Admin/NewsController.php
public function index()
{
    $modelClass = $this->modelClass;
    $news = $this->$modelClass->find()
                                    ->order(['created' => 'DESC']);
    $this->set(compact('news'));
}
```

I want to dynamically get the modelClass in order to make inheritance easier.

When I go to `/admin/news-manager/news`, the `$modelClass` value above returns `'NewsManager.News'`  and then the `find()` request returns the error `Undefined property: NewsController::$NewsManager.News`

How could I do to avoid having the plugin prefixed in `modelClass` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `loadModel()` (or as of 4.3 `fetchTable()`) without any arguments, that will then load the default model set for the controller, eg:

```php
$this->loadModel()->find()
```

or:

```php
$this->fetchTable()->find()
```